# Parse String to XML Document jdom2

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have a problem. I want to convert the string to a xml document.
But this code is throw exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.jdom2.Document
>           at ru.unicus.osp.Test.main(Test.java:17)

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<root><node1></node1></root>"));
        Document doc = (Document) db.parse(is);
    }
}
```

Got any ideas?

Comment: try `org.w3c.dom.Document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed two libraries here. The simplest thing that can be done is to change the import from:

```
import org.jdom2.Document;
```

to

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

So the code should look like:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       InputSource is = new InputSource();
       is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<root><node1></node1></root>"));
       Document doc = (Document) db.parse(is);  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two libraries here, DOM, and JDOM.

your current output `Document` is a JDOM document, it seems, but you are trying to cast a w3 DOM Document instance to be one, and you are failing.

If you want to have a JDOM Document as your output, then your code should likely be:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader("<root><node1></node1></root>"));
```

For a DOM document output, just use a DOM Document (`org.w3c.dom.Document`) instead of `org.jdom2.Document`